# override detected distribution in rvm (Ruby Version Manager)

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I work on Linux mint and rvm has already pre-built binaries for ubuntu, So I want to override the detected distro to ubuntu ? 
I found That I can override setting in rvm/user/db
So what's the entry that I should write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you can not override the detected platform, this is not supported - feel free to open a ticket requesting that functionality: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

you can install the binary rubies from other platforms (found here: https://rvm.io/binaries):

```
rvm mount -r <url to the binary>
```

also there is a ticket to use the debian binaries for mint: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2134